# MySQL syntax error while creating a UPDATE Trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am trying to create a trigger on updating the salary field of this table.
*customers(ID, Name, Age, Address, Salary)* from this site [SQL Trigger](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/plsql/plsql_triggers.htm)
While creating it shows the following error

MySQL said:
**#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'OR INSERT OR UPDATE ON customers 
FOR EACH ROW 
WHEN (NEW.ID > 0) 
DECLARE 
' at line 2**

Here is the code snippet:

```
BEFORE DELETE OR INSERT OR UPDATE ON customers 
FOR EACH ROW 
WHEN (NEW.ID > 0) 
DECLARE 
   sal_diff number; 
BEGIN `enter code here`
   sal_diff := :NEW.salary  - :OLD.salary; 
   dbms_output.put_line('Old salary: ' || :OLD.salary); 
   dbms_output.put_line('New salary: ' || :NEW.salary); 
   dbms_output.put_line('Salary difference: ' || sal_diff); 
END
```

*Note that, I'm using phpMyAdmin. Does dbms_ouput.put_line() works there?*

Comment: You’re reading a site for PL/SQL which is for Oracle and using MySQL. They don’t use the same language. Look for MySQL documentation

Comment: And, likewise, [`DBMS_OUTPUT`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_output.htm#ARPLS036) is a package available in Oracle database.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments, you are using Oracle syntax, it can't work on MySQL.

Then, there's no reason to have this trigger on DELETE and INSERT because your aim is to compute the salary difference on a specific row before and after it get updated. You can't have a value NEW on DELETE, and you can't have a value OLD on INSERT.
Thus your computation is only meaningful on UPDATE.

Here's the correct MySQL syntax (I am assuming that you have a column `sal_diff`  on your table)

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `update_sal_diff`
BEFORE UPDATE ON `customers `
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET NEW.sal_diff = NEW.salary  - OLD.salary;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

If this is not what you are trying to achieve, edit your question and add clear requirements